# How can I create a view which needs a parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Here is my table structure:

```
-- users
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+
| id |  name  |       email         | password |      cookie        |
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+
| 1  | Jack   | jack0011@gmail.com  | 098u23r8 | kj3409t34034u8rf   |
| 2  | Peter  | wanter_s@gmail.com  | k0io34r4 | m32i0949y834rf34   |
| 3  | Martin | dr.mrtn@yahoo.com   | fg345t34 | rf34r89p23r49i34   |
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+

-- user_details
+---------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| user_id | age  |          about       |      date      |
+---------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| 1       | 32   | NULL                 | NULL           |
| 2       | NULL | A senior developer   | 1992-02-10     |
| 3       | 18   | NULL                 | 1999-01-06     |
+---------+------+----------------------+----------------+
```

Now I want to make a `VIEW` like this:

```
Create View `user` as 
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email
       ud.age, ud.about, ud.date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_details -- there is a trigger which makes a row in this table after insert in users table.
ON u.id = ud.user_id
```

Now I want to use `VIEW` above for a specific user. I can do that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :user_id
```

But I guess that's lots of waste processing. Anyway, how can I append something like this `AND u.id = :user_id` to the `VIEW`'s logic every time?

Comment: Just query the view like you did in the last snippet. Any half-descent optimizer would handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Views itself do not have any parameter. However, you can filter in the `select` statement you use to get data from the `view`, just like in any other `select`:

```
select from `user` where id = :id
```

There is no other way to include dynamic filtering within a view.

Answer (score 0):

View can not have any input parameter so you have to create view and then you can call view as a select query by using where condition according to whatever result you want. For Example :-

```
select from `user` where id = 1;
select from `user` where id in (1,2);
```